# How to do Drag and Drop in UICollectionView that has UITableView inner in cell like Trello app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview, trello

I'm having UICollectionView that scrolls horizontally. Each collection view cell has a table view that scrolls vertically. I want to implement drag and drop of table view cell with in the table view itself as well as between different tableviews within each collection view cell. 
Need some tutorial or help for that.

Answer (score 0):

OK gonna have to go full custom for this, so this is roughly what you need to do:

Long press gesture or something on the cell, double tap whatever you like, which does a delegate method to controller that passes the cell to the parent collectionview, then the controller so controller has collectionview and cell.

On receiving the delegate method you wanna snapshot the cell:

```
UIView.snapshot.....
```

and then delete the cell from the tableview, while making a new dummy UIView of the cell under the users finger.

Now when you release the cell from the gesture another delegate method, dropped Cell, in position: CGPoint

Using this position find the CollectionView cell you dropped it on

```
collectionView.itemAtPoint (or something close to that)
```

Now convert the CGpoint to the collectionView Rect

```
collectionView.convertPoint
```

find the tableView cell closest to the point where you dropped the cell, and re-add the cell to that tableview.

Youll have to make a small MovingModel, that contains the model of the cell for when you drop it on the new tableview.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @SeanLintern88 , do you have a demo of this, if yes then please share with me, its urgent requirement. I don't have much experience in ios. Thanks in advance

Comment: no, thats why I said its 100% custom you will have to build each part yourself, its not too difficult just do it step by step...

Comment: can you give me your skype id?  so i can get some help from you if needed? @SeanLintern88